# XMPP - Enabling Chat Among Users

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I implemented an iPhone chat application using XMPP protocol and Openfire server. I can list the users in XMPP Client but I don't know how to enable chat among those users.

I would like to know:

1. How to send text to selected user
2. How to promote a chat window and initiate text chat between those two users

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XMPPFramework is just that, a framework. You must construct a full UI and all the other logic necessary to create a chat application.

To send a chat message to another user, you would use code similar to this:

```
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:@"Message text here"];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"recipient.jid.com"];
[message addChild:body];

[xmppStream sendElement:message];
```

You would need to create the UI using a UITextField to enter the message text for instance. XMPPFramework is the low-level code to send and receive XMPP stanzas. You would also need to add code to where XMPP Messages are received, probably use the `isChatMessage` method and then notify the recipient that they've received a message, display it to them and allow them to reply.

Comment: Thanks marc it was realy helpful.. i have another doubt the string value for attribute to "recipient.jid.com".. is this our hostname..??

Comment: for example my hostname is 182.18.0.162.. so my to should be like nik@182.18.0.162.. is this right ?.. but i cant send text to selected user.. chat is not working..